# Is there a general formula for the following expression?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

I am working on a proof, and came to the point where I need a general expression for the formula, taking real numbers $x_i$ and an integer $k$, of :

> $(x_1+x_2+...+x_n)^k$

I now I could apply the Newtons Binomial Theorem several times to get this expression. But, do you know what I should get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [Multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).